# How to add navigation controller in landscape ios6

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, ios6

While am trying to add  navigation controller in landscape based app ios6 application it shows in Portrait Mode only like in the image,What change should i made?[image]

In app delegate file coding,

```
 self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
 self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
[self.window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this to add `UINavigationController` in your app :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // start of your application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions
    // ...

    viewController = [[ViewController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
    [self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [viewController release];
    [navigationController release];

    return YES;
}
```